# Show that $V_n^k=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

Show that $$V_n^k=\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}.$$
The general formula for variations is $V_n^k=n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1).$ We have $$\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}=\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)(n-k-1)...2.1}.$$ What can I do next?

Comment: All you have to do is cancel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the numerator as follows and cancel out terms:
$$\frac{n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1)(n-k)\dots(2)(1)}{(n-k)(n-k-1) \dots (2)(1)} = n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-k+1)=V_n^k$$

Comment: But why $(n-k+1)$ in the numerator? Where does this come from?

Comment: Because $n!$ is the product of all the integers less than $n$. So since $(n-k+1)$ is less than $n$ it is included. Maybe an example might clear this up. Set $n=5$ and $k=2$. Our fraction becomes $$\frac{5(4)(3)(2)(1)}{(2)(1)}$$ but notice here that $4 = (5-2+1) = n-k+1$.
No matter what choice of $k$ we make we know that $(n-k+1)$ is certainly in the numerator.

Comment: But how do we know it isnt' equal to $(n-1)$ or $(n-2)$ for example?

Comment: We don't mind if it is equal to those, because it is still in the numerator and we can cancel it. We'd just be left with less terms multiplying off each other on the RHS. Think about whether you can write every term in the form $(n - k + c)$ for some number $c$.